# Scala Map: mysterious syntactic sugar?

Tags: scala, maps, syntactic-sugar, scala-collections

I have just found out this syntax for a scala `Map` (used here in *mutable* form)

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]()
m("Hello") = 5
println(m) //PRINTS Map(Hello -> 5)
```

Now I'm not sure whether this is syntactic *sugar* built in to the language, or whether something more fundamental is going on here involving the fact that a map extends a `PartialFunction`. Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you mean (it would be nice if you could be more explicit)

```
m("Hello") = 5
```

that is intended syntactic sugar for

```
m.update("Hello", 5)
```

independent of what m is. This is analogous to

```
m("Hello")
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
m.apply("Hello")
```

(I'm just reading "Programming in Scala".)

Comment: Could you point me to the page in Programming in Scala; unless I'm being blind I can't find it. I'm really not convinced that this is syntactic sugar at all

Comment: Can you indicate where the "update" method is in the hierarchy? I can't even find it!

Comment: That's the bit in "Programming in Scala" which says that m("Hello") = 5 is equivalent to m.update("Hello", 5). But I can't actually see that Map has a method "update" on it.

Answer (score 5):

@starblue is correct.  Note that you can also do rather creative things with `update` such as returning values *other* than what was assigned.  For example:

```
val a = Map(1 -> "one")      // an immutable Map[Int, String]
val b = a(2) = "two"
val c = b(5) = "five"
val d = c(1) = "uno"

d == Map(1 -> "uno", 2 -> "two", 5 -> "five")       // => true
```

This works because `immutable.Map#update` returns an instance of the new `Map`.  It looks a little odd to the C-trained eye, but you get used to it.

Comment: So "m(K) = V" is syntactic sugar for m.update(K, V). How can one tell that this is the case? What other methods may have syntactic sugar applied to them? And I can't even see a method update on Map (or any of its inheritees) in the scaladoc. How would I even know that Map had such a method?